# Convert data frame to strong typed data set?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following class, the `run` returns a list of ints from a database table.

```
class ItemList(sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, jdbcSqlConn: String) {
  def run(date: LocalDate) = {
    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"dbo.GetList('$date')"
    )).load()
  }
}
```

The following code

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf.setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[*]"))
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val itemListJob = new ItemList(sqlContext, jdbcSqlConn)
val processed = itemListJob.run(rc, priority).select("id").map(d => {
  runJob.run(d) // d expected to be int
})
processed.saveAsTextFile("c:\\temp\\mpa")
```

get the error of

```
[error] ...\src\main\scala\main.scala:39: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Row
[error]  required: Int
[error]       runJob.run(d)
[error]                  ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I tried

1. `val processed = itemListJob.run(rc, priority).select("id").as[Int].map(d =>`
2. `case class itemListRow(id: Int); ....as[itemListRow].`

Both of them got errors of

> Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.

**Update:**
I'm trying to add the import implicits statements

1. `import sc.implicits._` got error of

   > value implicits is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext
2. `import sqlContext.implicits._` is OK. However, the later statement of `processed.saveAsTextFile("c:\\temp\\mpa")` got the error of

   > value saveAsTextFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Int, java.time.LocalDate)]

Comment: What's the error when using `as[Int]`?

Comment: The error is `Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.`

Comment: Did you try `import spark.implicits._`?

Comment: It got the error of `not found: value spark` on `import spark.implicits._`

Comment: You need to create a spark session as described here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession

Comment: I saw `sqlContext` in your codes. So you can use `import sqlContext.implicits._`.

Comment: Or `import sqlContext.sparkSession.implicits._`

Comment: Thanks. I actually have one "SC". Just wondering if it's the best way to use implicit? Or any other approachea?

Comment: It must be either `SQLContext` or `SparkSession`. You can also get `SparkSession` from `Dataset.sparkSession`

Comment: @zsxwing I changed the code to use all data frame/dataset. However, it got a new error. I've posted a question for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168394/spark-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-no-encoder-found-for-java-time-l?noredirect=1#comment75353157_44168394

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply change the line with `select("id")` to be as follows:

```
select("id").as[Int]
```

You should import the implicits for converting `Rows` to Ints.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._ // <-- import implicits that add the "magic"
```

---

You could also change `run` to include the conversion as follows (note the comments to the lines I added):

```
class ItemList(sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, jdbcSqlConn: String) {
  def run(date: LocalDate) = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._ // <-- import implicits that add the "magic"
    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"dbo.GetList('$date')"
    )).load()
    .select("id") // <-- take only "id" (which Spark pushes down and hence makes your query faster
    .as[Int] // <-- convert Row into Int
  }
}
```

---

> value saveAsTextFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Int, java.time.LocalDate)]

The **compilation** error is because you try to use `saveAsTextFile` operation on `Dataset` that is not available.

Writing in Spark SQL is through [DataFrameWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter) that's available using [write](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@write:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[T]) operator:

> **write: DataFrameWriter[T]** Interface for saving the content of the non-streaming Dataset out into external storage.

So you should do the following:

```
processed.write.text("c:\\temp\\mpa")
```

*Done!*

Comment: I changed the `ItemList.run()` to return a DataSet as you suggested. However, I need to to add `import sqlContext.implicits._` before calling `val processed = itemListJob.run(...).map(....)`.