# Parallelism: rdd.parallelize(....) vs dataSet.map(...)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have implemented a Spark application using both DataFrame/DataSet and RDD. I submitted the application to my local development environment of Spark 2.1.1. My PC has **eight** CPU cores.

**DateFrame/DataSet**

```
val date : LocalDate = ....
val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf.setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[*]"))
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val itemListJob = new ItemList(sqlContext, jdbcSqlConn)
import sqlContext.implicits._ 
val processed = itemListJob.run(rc, priority).select("id").map(d => {
  val (a, b) = runJob.run(d, date) // returns a tuple of (int, java.sql.Date), which are the passed parameters.
  s"$a, $b"
})

class ItemList(sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, jdbcSqlConn: String) {
  def run(date: LocalDate) = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._ 
    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"dbo.GetList('$date')"
    )).load()
    .select("id") 
    .as[Int] 
  }
}
processed.write.text("c:\\temp\\mpa")
```

**RDD**

```
val itemList = itemListJob.run(rc, priority).select("id").rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[Int]).collect()

val processed = sc.parallelize(itemList).map(d => {
  runJob.run(d, rc) // returns a tuple of (int, LocalDate), which are the passed parameters.
})
processed.saveAsTextFile("c:\\temp\\mpa")
```

The RDD application split and generated eight text files while the Dataframe/DataSet one generated only one file. Does it mean the RDD ran eight `runJob.run()` in parallel while the DataFrame/DataSet approach only ran one a time without concurrency?

I want the runJob.run(), which does the main workload and will also make a jdbc call, to be run distributed and in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But collecting data back to driver to parallelize is really not necessary. You can just call `Dataset.repartition(...)` to split your one partition into multiple ones. A better way is using other `jdbc` overloads to load data from JDBC, such as http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@jdbc(url:String,table:String,predicates:Array[String],connectionProperties:java.util.Properties):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame or http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@jdbc(url:String,table:String,predicates:Array[String],connectionProperties:java.util.Properties):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame to avoid shuffle.

Comment: What's the "shuffle"you mentioned?

Comment: This is a basic concept of Spark. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the number of files produced is a good indicator of the parallelism in the last step. (I can think of a few corner cases where this might not be the case, but that's irrelevant here)

`sc.parallelize` when running locally should split according to the number of cores.

However, in both cases, you would be using only 1 core to read over the jdbc connection, and in the RDD case, you additionally `collect()` the data back to the driver, then `parallelize` back to the task.

The preferred approach is to use `repartition` rather than `collect` and then `parallelize`. And even better would be to always be doing things in parallel. In the case of loading the data frame over jdbc, take a look at whether using the parameters `partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartition` ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)) might be applicable in order to run in parallel from the very start.

Comment: I want the runJob.run(), which does the main workload and will also make a jdbc call, to be run distributed and in parallel. Which approach is better?

Comment: I would probably prefer the RDD in this case since it is a bit simpler. Just call `repartition` instead of `collect` and `parallelize`