# Spark No Encoder found for java.io.Serializable in Map[String, java.io.Serializable]

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing a spark job that the dataset is pretty flexible, it's defined as `Dataset[Map[String, java.io.Serializable]]`.

now the problem start to show up, spark runtime complains about `No Encoder found for java.io.Serializable`. I've tried kyro serde, still showing the same error message.

the reason why I have to use this weird Dataset type is because I have flexible fields per Row. and the map looks like:

```
Map(
  "a" -> 1,
  "b" -> "bbb",
  "c" -> 0.1,
  ...
)
```

is there anyway in Spark to handle this flexible dataset type?

EDIT: 
here is the solid code anyone can try.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

object SerdeTest extends App {
  val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()


  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val ret: Dataset[Record] = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(0 to 10)
    .map(
      t => {
        val row = (0 to t).map(
          i => i -> i.asInstanceOf[Integer]
        ).toMap

        Record(map = row)
      }
    ).toDS()

  val repartitioned = ret.repartition(10)


  repartitioned.collect.foreach(println)
}

case class Record (
                  map: Map[Int, java.io.Serializable]
                  )
```

the above code will give you error Encoder not found:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for java.io.Serializable
- map value class: "java.io.Serializable"
- field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map")
```

Comment: @thebluephantom added code, can directly run in intelliJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the answer, one way to solve this is to use Kyro serde framework, code change is very minimum, just need to make an implicit Encoder using Kyro and bring that into the context whenever serialization is needed.

here is the code example I got working(can directly run in IntelliJ or equivalent IDE):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object SerdeTest extends App {
  val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()


  import sparkSession.implicits._

  // here is the place you define your Encoder for your custom object type, like in this case Map[Int, java.io.Serializable]
  implicit val myObjEncoder: Encoder[Record] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Record]
  val ret: Dataset[Record] = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(0 to 10)
    .map(
      t => {
        val row = (0 to t).map(
          i => i -> i.asInstanceOf[Integer]
        ).toMap

        Record(map = row)
      }
    ).toDS()

  val repartitioned = ret.repartition(10)


  repartitioned.collect.foreach(
    row => println(row.map)
  )
}

case class Record (
                  map: Map[Int, java.io.Serializable]
                  )
```

this code will produce the expected results:

```
Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 5, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 4)
Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 5, 1 -> 1, 6 -> 6, 2 -> 2, 7 -> 7, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 4)
Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 1)
Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 4)
Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
Map(0 -> 0)
Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 5, 1 -> 1, 6 -> 6, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 4)
Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 5, 10 -> 10, 1 -> 1, 6 -> 6, 9 -> 9, 2 -> 2, 7 -> 7, 3 -> 3, 8 -> 8, 4 -> 4)
Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 5, 1 -> 1, 6 -> 6, 9 -> 9, 2 -> 2, 7 -> 7, 3 -> 3, 8 -> 8, 4 -> 4)
Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 5, 1 -> 1, 6 -> 6, 2 -> 2, 7 -> 7, 3 -> 3, 8 -> 8, 4 -> 4)
```